# Installing SQL express after installing visual studio community 2013

Tags: sql-server

I have just downloaded and installed Visual studio 2013, and now I want to download SQL Server. But I'm not sure which one is right for me.

I have a 64 bit Windows 8.1, and I wish to learn .Net programming and data connectivity. The last time I tried, SQL Server wouldn't connect, so I uninstalled and re-installed.
That didn't work, so I restored my system in order to start fresh.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx?TabIndex=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the Express Edition (with tools)

Make sure you take note of the instance name (best to use default in your case probably i.e. no instance name)

also make sure you use windows / mixed mode authentication and add yourself in as an administrator

when you open up management studio just enter localhost into the sever name and you should connect fine

there is a sarcastic walkthrough here
http://www.istartedsomething.com/20140616/the-12-step-process-to-download-microsoft-sql-server-express-2014/